# PHP - blueimp custom upload directory - empty list on reload

Tags: php, upload, blueimp, filelist

i use blueimp on php. In HTML i've put a hidden input field to submit the User_ID (after login, ID of the user from DB) to the Upload Handler as $_POST value. I use the User_ID value as upload directory name to separate each users files from each other.

HTML:

```
    <form id="fileupload" action="server/php/index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_file_directory" id="user_file_directory" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_ID']; ?>">
```

index.php :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$user_filedirectory = $_POST['user_file_directory'];
$urlHolder = 'user_'.$user_filedirectory.'/';
$options = array(
                'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ds-admin/server/php/'.$urlHolder,
                'upload_url' => './server/php/'.$urlHolder.'/',
);
if($urlHolder){
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options , true , null);
}
?>
```

This works fine to upload something and after upload i can see the thumbnails and even enlarge them. But on a reload of the HTML the list of existing Files is empty, thou the files do still exist on server inside the right folder. On re upload of a file i will see only the new files.

How can i retrieve the content of the custom upload folder on HTML Page load? do i have to set the download-file-directory within the script part of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found!

i only made the mistake not to start the session within the index.php of blueimp. after that everything woks like a flaw! Every user gets his own up/Download directory based on his User-ID from DataBase (saved in Session).

my working index.php looks now like this:

```
<?php
       /* SESSION START IS IMPORTANT   ;) */
session_start();

/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Example 5.14
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$user_filedirectory = $_SESSION['user_ID'];
$urlHolder = 'user_'.$user_filedirectory.'/';
$options = array(
                'upload_dir' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ds-admin/server/php/'.$urlHolder,
                'upload_url' => './server/php/'.$urlHolder.'',
);
if($urlHolder){
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options , true , null);
} 
?>
```

Lajos Arpad gave me the right hint: $_POST can't work for listing the directory content, for its value will be passed only after a Form-Action... and that is too late.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you check for the files in your `$_POST` array, which has the values only when they were included in a post request. Now, the problem is that you do not store them somewhere when the post occurred:

```
if (isset($_POST['user_file_directory'])) {
    //store the values...
}
```

You can store the values using a database, like MySQL, to name an example, or you can store into a local file the list of files, or you can store in the `$_SESSION` variable, or, you can even live without storing it if you know where the files are located, then you can use [scandir](https://php.net/manual/ro/function.scandir.php).

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I do store this value in a Session variable. so i do know where the files are. but how to tell blueimp that the file directory to look for files (not to upload to) is "user_" + "Session[user_ID]" ?

Comment: In PHP, in general, you can tell it this way: "user_".$_SESSION["user_id"], note, that dot(.) is the string concatenation operator in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an older post and therefore my contribution may not be relevant, but this post helped me answer a question and I wanted to provide my specific solution to the same problem.

I needed to be able to set the name of the folder with a string I am generating from before and passing around as a post variable. This string is stored in the database and it is client specific. But will not be used after the application process is finished.

The uploader does everything we need except it uses the session id as the folder name. With this system, everything works as intended, while the session variable exists.

Anyway, here is what I did:
In the index.php page, at the root of the uploading system, I did the following:

```
$app_code = $_POST['app_code'];
session_id($app_code);
session_start();
```

That's it in the index page.

In the Class UploadHandler.php page, I just set the following

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
```

to this

```
function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->response = array();
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/'.basename($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_NAME')),
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
        'user_dirs' => true,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
```

And that's it!

Now the system works as intended for me. Thanks so much!